# How to continuously distribute a fixed set of labels between nodes in a system?

Tags: architecture, scalability, distributed-computing

I was not sure if such design question is suitable here but according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41469/is-there-a-stack-overflow-for-design-questions it's not completely off limits.

In my system I have a number of nodes that download large files and process them. Each file is identified by a unique label. Based on that label a node can build a proper URL and download a corresponding file. The files change over time (often) so the nodes have to download them continuously and keep processing.

In my current architecture I have different sets (not overlapping) of labels assigned to different nodes. But this is not an ideal solution because the files' sizes change so the work is not always evenly distributed. Also handling fault tolerance is more complicated as I need a hot backup for each processing node to fail over.

One possible solution I consider is to have a queue (FIFO) of labels and each node would fetch a label from head, do its processing and then return it to the end of the queue.
This solution addresses the problem of even work distribution but again introduces another issue with fault tolerance. If a node fails during processing then we lose the label and this is not acceptable in this particular system. Now we could have a process that monitors the content of a queue if it has all the labels.

But I'm looking for a more elegant and sound solution that would address the even work distribution and fault tolerance without too much complexity in this particular system. Any ideas?

Comment: >  we lose the label and this is not acceptable in this particular system - how labels are added into the system? Why it is lost if node fails to download it, isn't it just not downloaded in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed with the queue approach, but add fault tolerance by an acknowledgment mechanism, such as the mechanisms you'll find in [Amazon SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/MessageLifecycle.html)) or in [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) (see [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html), under "message acknowledgment).

The idea is that when a consumer pulls an item from the queue, the item is not removed from the queue. It is only removed from the queue after the consumer acknowledges successful processing of that item. If the consumer pulls an item and does not acknowledge for a certain prescribed amount of time, then the message because available again in the queue, and a different consumer will handle that message.

Notice that this may create a situation in which the same message is processed twice. This is o.k. if you processing action is idempotent (i.e. doing the action twice yields the same result as doing it once), but if it isn't, then you need to add custom guards to handle this situation.

In short, if reliability is your concern, use one of the available reliable queue services such as those mentioned above.